# Change ndk-build output locations

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, ndk-build

My app has the following structure

```
Android
|
|-> app
|    |
|    |-> build [1]
|    |-> src
|    |    |-> main
|    |    |     |-> assets
|    |    |     |-> java
|    |    |     |-> jni 
|    |    |     |     |-> Android.mk
|    |    |     |     |-> Application.mk
|    |    |     |
|    |    |     |-> jniLibs
|    |    |     |      |-> armeabi
|    |    |     |      |-> armeabi-v7a
|    |    |     |
|    |    |     |-> res
|    |    |     |-> AndroidManifest.xml
|
|-> build [2]
```

I am building my `.so` libraries with `ndk-build` command in a linux machine. I use it like:

```
<my_ndk_path>/ndk-build -C <my_project_path>/Android/app/src/main/
```

The build process works fine and output files are produced with no errors.

My **problem** is that the result files are not "directed to the proper position"

The `libs` generated at :

```
.app/src/main/libs/armeabi-v7a/libMyGeneratedLibrary.so
.app/src/main/libs/armeabi/libMyGeneratedLibrary.so
```

and the `obj` files at :

```
.app/src/main/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libMyGeneratedLibrary.so
.app/src/main/obj/local/armeabi/libMyGeneratedLibrary.so
```

I would like the output to produced in different locations:

1. The `libs` at `jniLibs`.
   ie. `./app/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi*`
2. The `obj` under one of the build folders. ie. `build`[1] or `build`[2].

Is there any possible way to achieve that by changing some parameter to the `.mk` files or to the build command?

---

**Edit**

`TARGET_OUT` does not seem to work in NDK r6b

Executing command `ndk-build -C Android/app/src/main/ TARGET_OUT='Android/app/src/main/jniLibs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)'`

Warnings as the following appear for each generated file.

```
android-ndk-r6b/build/core/build-binary.mk:217: warning: overriding commands for target 'Android/app/src/main/jniLibs//objs/***/****.o'
android-ndk-r6b/build/core/build-binary.mk:217: warning: ignoring old commands for target 'Android/app/src/main/jniLibs//objs/***/****.o'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit** (for anyone that step on this topic with newer NDK versions):

- Use `NDK_LIBS_OUT` to change libs output *(requires NDK r9 and above)*
- Use `NDK_OUT` to change obj output *(requires NDK r7c and above)*

Build command is is:

```
ndk-build NDK_LIBS_OUT=./jniLibs NDK_OUT=./obj
```

---

**Previous answer** (applicable in any case):

How I solve it. Not really elegant but at least it works.

Because my building mechanism is quite complicated so I had a couple of custom gradle tasks and scripts too, it doesn't really matter to me the single command for the build.

So I kept build command as is

```
<my_ndk_path>/ndk-build -C <my_project_path>/Android/app/src/main/
```

Add a the folder creation (-p don't generate error if it exists)

```
mkdir -p <my_project_path>/Android/app/src/main/jniLibs/
```

Then I move the .so files to the final location with the sync command.

```
rsync -avh --remove-source-files                        \
      <my_project_path>/Android/app/src/main/libs/*     \
      <my_project_path>/Android/app/src/main/jniLibs/
```

You can do something similar for the `obj` folder. I just modified my .gitignore so I left it as is.

Answer (score 35):

You can use `NDK_LIBS_OUT` to change libs output and `NDK_OUT` to change obj output.
Just like this : `ndk-build NDK_LIBS_OUT=./jniLibs NDK_OUT=./obj`

Comment: This does not really work for me. It looks like the these are ignored from the NDK. Maybe it is part of a later one as I have a pretty old version r6b.

Comment: `NDK_OUT` was added in revision 7c; `NDK_LIBS_OUT` was added in revision 9.

Comment: Where should NDK_LIBS_OUT be added, in Android.mk or Application.mk?

Comment: NDK_LIBS_OUT should be added as an argument to ndk-build call

Comment: So how do you add an argument to the ndk-build call? Gradle **3.2.1** keeps telling me that `arguments` is invalid.

Comment: Anyway you can do that for include files? Something like `NDK_LIBS_OUT` for the `lib/` directory and `NDK_INCLUDES_OUT` for the `include/` directory?

Answer (score 5):

If you need to build for all available architectures, please use argument:

```
    TARGET_OUT='<your_build_dir>/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)'
```

If just one target architecture is enough, then use argument:

```
    TARGET_OUT=<your_build_dir>
```

Comment: This does not work for me either it the `$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)` which I need does not take any effect, the lib is produced ones in the jniLibs folder and not inside the `armeabi`, `armeabi-v7a`

Comment: Could you copy&paste here your exact command line when using the above mentioned parameter? I'm curious as I used that myself succesfully couple of hours ago. Also, what is your NDK version?

Comment: Sadly, its a pretty old version r6b. I tried this with many different ways and also tried to add `TARGET_OUT := ...` to `Application.mk` when it passes and not fails I get the warnings that I added to my original post.

Answer (score 2):

The better and more simple way to specify out put locations is linking [Gradle to your native library](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/gradle-external-native-builds).
After that, using `buildStagingDirectory` options in `ndkBuild` block to specify out put location:

```
android {
    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            // Tells Gradle to put outputs from external native
            // builds in the path specified below.
            buildStagingDirectory  "src/main/libs"
        }
    }
}
```

Then just `Sync Gradle` and build, done.

Comment: The [buildStagingDirectory](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/4.1/com/android/build/api/dsl/NdkBuild#buildstagingdirectory) specifies the path to external native build output directory, to replace the default `<project_dir>/.cxx/`. I agree that the official explanation above may be confusing, but this directory contains intermediate build files (logs, objects, etc.). The `.so` files go normally to `<project_dir>/build` directory. See the [discussion](https://github.com/android/ndk/issues/1445#issuecomment-773914155).

Comment: Both `cmake` and `ndkBuild` sections seem to allow `buildStagingDirectory` option, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest way is [linking](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/gradle-external-native-builds) Android.mk file to Gradle, like this:

```
android {
    ...
    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            path file('src/main/jni/Android.mk')
        }
    }
}
```

Then just click on **Sync Now** and build the project