# Force CMake in verbose mode via Gradle and the Android NDK

Tags: gradle, android-ndk, cmake

I'm using Gradle and CMake to compile an Android NDK project from the command line. Previously, I was using Ant and `ndk-build` but I'm trying to migrate the project completely to Gradle and CMake.

In my `build.gradle` I have the following lines to invoke CMake:

```
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
    }
}
```

Now how can I force CMake to print all compiler calls to the console before it makes them? Specifically, I want to see just how CMake runs the compiler and linker.

I've already tried the following, all to no avail:

1) In my `CMakeLists.txt` I have put the following line:

```
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on)
```

Didn't have any effect.

2) I have started the build like this:

```
./gradlew build --info
```

Gradle printed some stuff, but no compiler calls.

3) And like this:

```
./gradlew build --debug
```

Gradle printed lots of stuff, but no compiler calls.

So none of those three attempts did what I wanted which makes me wonder how can I see how CMake runs clang on my individual source files?

Comment: Check `.externalNativeBuild` directory under project root; it may contain all information relevant for you

Comment: Indeed, great, thanks! There's a `build.ninja` log file which contains all the essential information. If you want to post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: See also some update: I finally reached my desktop to test the flags manually.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

***Disclaimer:*** the following description applies to the version of Android Gradle Plugin (**AGP**) that was the latest at the time I updated this Answer (*aug '21*). If you are curious, have a look at the [history of edits](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/43442227/timeline).

As [@artyomd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7362111/artyomd) has noticed, for [AGP 4.2.0](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#native-build-output) and higher, you can set `android.native.buildOutput` gradle property to `verbose` to force cmake logging.

In Android Studio, **gradle** creates directory `.cxx` under the module root, for each module that has NDK integration, via CMake or ndk-build.

For CMake, the gradle plugin is quite verbose. For each build variant it creates separate subdirectory, e.g. `.cxx/cmake/debug/x86` or `.cxx/cmake/release/armeabi-v7a`, etc.

Each directory contains some useful files: **cmake_build_command.txt**  describes the actual parameters passed to CMake; **android_gradle_build.json** shows what parameters the gradle plugin derived for your binaries; from **build.ninja** you can deduce the how these parameters were applied for each compilation or linkage step.

For `ndk-build`, the `android_gradle_build.json` file is also quite useful. `ndkBuild_build_command.txt` lists all parameters passed to **ndk-build** command, and `ndkBuild_build_output.txt` is the unabridged output of that command. You can easily add **`V=1`** to the arguments, e.g.

```
externalNativeBuild {
  ndkBuild {
    cppFlags "-std=c++11"
    arguments "APP_STL=c++_static", "APP_OPTIM=release", "NDK_DEBUG=0", "V=1"
    abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
  }
}
```

For `CMake`, the relevant argument is `"-DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON"` (see *[explanation
and alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2673355/192373)*):

```
externalNativeBuild {
  cmake {
    cppFlags "-std=c++11"
    arguments "-DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON"
    abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
  }
}
```

But, as [@user7860670](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7860670/user7860670) has observed, the recent versions of AGP ignore this flag.

Without `CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE`, the Gradle Console displays:

```
:app:externalNativeBuildDebug
Build native-lib armeabi-v7a
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp.o
[2/2] Linking CXX shared library ../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi-v7a/libnative-lib.so
```

With `"-DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL=ON"`, I ***used to get*** tons of output:

```
:app:externalNativeBuildDebug
Build native-lib armeabi-v7a

[1/2] /Users/alex/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang++  --target=armv5te-none-linux-androideabi --gcc-toolchain=/Users/alex/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64 --sysroot=/Users/alex/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-14/arch-arm  -Dnative_lib_EXPORTS -isystem /Users/alex/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include -isystem /Users/alex/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi-v7a/include -isystem /Users/alex/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/backward -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv5te -mtune=xscale -msoft-float -fno-integrated-as -mthumb -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv5te -mtune=xscale -msoft-float -fno-integrated-as -mthumb -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security   -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -fPIC -MD -MT CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp.o -c /Users/alex/test/egl/app/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp
[2/2] : && /Users/alex/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang++  --target=armv5te-none-linux-androideabi --gcc-toolchain=/Users/alex/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64 --sysroot=/Users/alex/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-14/arch-arm -fPIC -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv5te -mtune=xscale -msoft-float -fno-integrated-as -mthumb -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv5te -mtune=xscale -msoft-float -fno-integrated-as -mthumb -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security   -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -shared -Wl,-soname,libnative-lib.so -o ../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi-v7a/libnative-lib.so CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp.o  -llog -lEGL -lGLESv2 -lm "/Users/alex/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/armeabi-v7a/libc++_static.a" "-latomic" && :
```

Not anymore. As far as I know, this information is filtered by Gradle Plugin and is completely lost. I can recover it only manually: run the command

```
/Users/alex/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.10.2.4988404/bin/cmake --build app/.cxx/cmake/debug/armeabi-v7a
```

You can use the Terminal window (**Alt-F12**) of Android Studio. This will invoke ninja with **`-v`** flag when `-DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON` was used to sync C++ with Gradle.

Note that the expected file `.cxx/cmake/debug/armeabi-v7a/cmake_build_output.txt` does not contain interesting information (unless you have problems with CMake configuration *per se*).

**P.S.** with this **3.6.0** Gradle Plugin, if you have a compilation error, then the whole command line for compiler is shown in Build Output window, no matter whether you set `CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE` or not. Actually, twice: once, in black on white (I don't use the dark theme), second time, in brown on white, after

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
```

Comment: gives me an error: `Could not find method arguments() for arguments on object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.CmakeOptions`

Comment: @peetonn: your mistake is that you put it in the **externalNativeBuild** block with **path** to CMakeLists.txt; but **arguments** should go into the other block, which is inside **android.defaultConfig**

Comment: PS I cannot imagine the mindset that came up with the idea to give the same names to entirely different entities in android.build.gradle DSL

Comment: Note: `"-DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL=ON"` does not seem to work anymore. `"-DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON"` worked for me. Not sure what has changed, I just installed android studio.

Comment: @AlexCohn I am using android studio on Windows 10. I can't find any .externalNativeBuild directory under module root. The only directories it has are .cxx, build, libs,and src. Do I need to change some gradle flags so as to make it produce this directory?

Comment: @ArpitAggarwal since this answer, the gradle plugin changed its naming convention. The directory that you see as `.cxx` was then called `.externalNativeBuild`. As far as I know, this did not change the internal logic of build process (*yet*).

Comment: `"-DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL=ON"` is getting completely ignored (cmake server issues a corresponding warning), `"-DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON"` does not seem to work anymore either

Comment: I set `"-DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON"` and I found the compile commands in `.cxx/cmake/<project>/armeabi-v7a/compile_commands.json` file.

Comment: How can we change ".cxx" directory?

Comment: @Top-Master I don't think you can change the `.cxx` directory, but the question is: why should you? Most likely, there is a better way to satisfy your needs.

Comment: At last, to change build directory (recently named `.cxx`), found correct solution in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60492487/8740349) with example!! see [CMake docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/4.1/com/android/build/api/dsl/Cmake) and details.

Comment: starting from AGP 4.2.0 you can set **android.native.buildOutput gradle** property to **verbose** to force cmake logging.
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin?hl=it-ch&skip_cache=true#native-build-output

Comment: thanks @artyomd I have included your update in the answer!

Comment: How/where do you set it? I tried `./gradlew -Pandroid.native.buildOutput=verbose build, but it doesn't do anything... I am on the gradle plugin 7.3.

Comment: @JonasVautherin as you can see, the progress of AGP has changed this bit significantly over years. I am not sure how the desired level of verbosity can be achieved these days.

Answer (score 3):

As an ugly workaround I've replaced ninja with my own executable that passes all the commands to the real ninja executable appending `"-v"`

Answer (score -5):

Try to update your gradle version.