# adding "-O0" to cppFlags fails to disable clang compile optimization in android studio

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I am building my app in debug mode, and I notice some errors saying "parent failed to evaluate: no location, value may have been optimized out". Therefore, I try to add "-O0" in my module build.gradle like this:

```
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        cppFlags "-O0 -frtti -fexceptions -std=c++11 -DANDROID_ARM_NEON=TRUE -mfloat-abi=softfp "
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
    }
}
```

But still, the same error shows up after adding "-O0". May I ask how to disable compiler optimization properly? My android Studio version is 2.3.3, my sdk tool version is 26.0.2 and my ndk version is 15.1.4

Comment: You may find it useful to check how the actual compilation command looks like, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/43442227/192373.

Answer (score 4):

You can override the build flags by adding the following to your `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
# Debug flags
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -O0")

# Release flags
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} -Ofast")
```

To verify this has worked check build output in:

```
app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/<buildconfig>/<architecture>/build.ninja
```

Look for a line starting with `FLAGS`. This doesn't actually replace the existing compiler flags it just appends your flags and these take precedence.

The default flags are inherited from `$ANDROID_NDK/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake` so you could edit that file directly, however, if you update your NDK these changes will be overwritten.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to disable optimization for release build, you can force Debug for C/C++ only:

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    externalNativeBuild {
      cmake {
        arguments '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug'
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply! May I ask how to disable optimization for debug build too?

Comment: For me, debug build comes with `-O0`. This is explicitly defined in `ndk-bundle/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake`