# compile optimized C++ for debug build in Android Studio

Tags: cmake, android-gradle-plugin

I want to set `jniDebuggable` to `false` in Android Studio's debug version, but it seems that it doesn't work even I set like this:

```
    debug {
        jniDebuggable false
    }
```

Since my JNI debug build is slow when running, I want to use the release build (faster than debug) when I debug my Java code.
Who can tell me how to do?

Comment: I use cmake to build the jni.

Comment: You probably want to build a release version of your C++ library in the Debug configuration of your Android Studio project. This has nothing to do with isDebuggable. You can override the cmake build arguments in build.gradle script.

Comment: You can use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45543443/192373) which is kind of reverse of your question.

Comment: Thanks, it works!

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments under the question post by [@Alex Cohn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/192373/alex-cohn), and adapted from [this answer he wrote to "*adding "-O0" to cppFlags fails to disable clang compile optimization in android studio*"](/a/45543443/11107541), you could do:

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    externalNativeBuild {
      cmake {
        arguments '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release'
```

That's if you don't need actual debug support for the native side of things (i.e. if by "debug", you really just mean running and testing your code without [a debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger)). If you do, use `RelWithDebInfo` instead of `Release`, which creates an optimized build with debug symbols (see [here for CMake docs on build out-of-box-defined types](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE.html)).

[See here for docs on Android NDK's CMake Guide](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cmake), and [here for docs on ExternalNativeBuildOptions](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/com/android/build/api/dsl/ExternalNativeBuildOptions).