# Change cmake directory in Android studio

Tags: android, cmake

I had copy an Android studio project from someone and i am unable to clean and rebuild the project. This is the following error pop out.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:externalNativeBuildCleanDebug'.

> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\cmake.exe''

Suppose the Users\Lenovo is the previous programmer user name where it is not my pc user name.

This is my build.gradle for app

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "linkdood.isenseocr_android"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            cppFlags ""
        }
    }
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "mips"
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        useProguard true
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
externalNativeBuild {
cmake {
    path 'CMakeLists.txt'
}
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
compile 'com.rmtheis:tess-two:8.0.0'
implementation project(':openCVLibrary331')
implementation project(':isenselib')
}
```

Is there anyway to solve this problem?

Comment: can you please post the content of build.gradle file

Comment: which build.gradle file? project, app, opencv, library. This android studio file is to generate aar file.

Comment: To change build directory (recently named `.cxx`), found correct solution in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60492487/8740349) with example!! see [CMake docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/4.1/com/android/build/api/dsl/Cmake) and details.

Answer (score 1):

Just comment `abiFilters` line under ndk in build.gradle and now sync,clean and rebuild,now the path will be changed, you can now reintroduce `abiFilters` and build again. This solved my problem.

Comment: Hi! thanks for replying. sorry for not updating. My code work after i remove

externalNativeBuild {
cmake {
    path 'CMakeLists.txt'
}
}

still, thanks for the information!!

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late to answer this question but it will help others.
You did remove externalNativeBuild { cmake { path 'CMakeLists.txt' } }  - but because of this you wont be able to use c++ file then...
for changing path do it like this:

Remove:

```
 externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path "CMakeLists.txt"
    }
}
```

..from app build gradle

- Right-click on the app module, select "Link C++ Project with Gradle" from the menu
- You will see a dialog
- Enter path of your cmakelist there and click ok
- Rebuild the project
- If it still doesn't work then invalidate the cache and restart android studio